# TRIM In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code and I am getting the error Unable to Parse, I am still learning the TRIM code so it maybe in that

```
SELECT    
   LEFT(dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.FAC_LOC_NR, 2) AS STATE, 
   (dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.TNG_SYS_NR) AS EHP_Code, RTRIM(LTRIM([FCT_TYP_CD])) + ' (' + RTRIM(LTRIM([Dep_Typ_CD]) + ')' AS [Course Owner]
   dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_NA AS [Course Title]
FROM         
   dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE ON dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.TNG_SYS_NR = dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_SYS_NR 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE_TYP ON dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_MDA_TYP_CD = dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE_TYP.TNG_TYP
GROUP BY 
   dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.FAC_LOC_NR, 
   LEFT(dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.FAC_LOC_NR, 2), 
   dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.TNG_SYS_NR, 
   dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_NA
```

Comment: First line, around the end: `RTRIM(LTRIM([Dep_Typ_CD])` is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Please include the full message. And you might be missing a comma after `AS [Course Owner]`.

Comment: I placed the additional ) now it is saying that dbo is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parentheses:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM([FCT_TYP_CD])) 
    + ' (' 
    RTRIM(LTRIM([Dep_Typ_CD])) <-- this is missing
    + ')' AS [Course Owner]
```

and you are missing a comma after `[Course Owner]`

Your query should be:

```
SELECT LEFT(dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.FAC_LOC_NR, 2) AS STATE, 
  (dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.TNG_SYS_NR) AS EHP_Code, 
  RTRIM(LTRIM([FCT_TYP_CD])) 
    + ' (' 
    RTRIM(LTRIM([Dep_Typ_CD])) --< parentheses missing
    + ')' AS [Course Owner],  -- < comma missing
  dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_NA AS [Course Title]
FROM dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail 
INNER JOIN dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE 
  ON dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.TNG_SYS_NR = dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_SYS_NR 
INNER JOIN dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE_TYP 
  ON dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_MDA_TYP_CD = dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE_TYP.TNG_TYP
GROUP BY dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.FAC_LOC_NR, 
  LEFT(dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.FAC_LOC_NR, 2), 
  dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.TNG_SYS_NR, 
  dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_NA
```